# Google Apps Script extract text under particular section in Google Docs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, paragraph

I have a Google Doc with 3 sections and there is text under each section header text.

[image]

2 sections with the same header text but different text and I would like to extract text under the last section. Is it possible that I can write script to read the "header" under the "Document Outline" that I need and extract the section only?

I tried script below and use `.search()` method to find "SECTION 01" however it return the position of 1st header in the document.

```
function extract_text() {
  const content = DocumentApp.openById("1MaWDAW2OrhNKNDesNIphb0hXQ1jWAbLrprpTRe4bCRw")
  .getBody()
  .getText()

  const position = content.search('Section 01')

  // result = 0
  console.log(position)
}
```

Comment: About `I would like to extract text under the last section.`, in your sample image, when several paragraphs are existing after the last "Section 01", what result do you want to retrieve? And, in order to correctly understand about your question, can you provide the sample Google Document and the sample output value you expect?

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

The method [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) has a second parameter called *fromIndex* that you can use to skip the first occurrence.

### Code

```
const searchTerm = "Section 01"
const position = content.indexOf(searchTerm, content.indexOf(searchTerm) + 1);
```

### Reference

- [String.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)